# Is it possible to make composable utility types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Dunno how to phrase the question, because I'm not sure what's possible or if it has better terminology, but here's the idea:

Let's say you have a utility type like:

```
type Unpack<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
// ☝️ gets a nested type from a given object type/interface
```

And a type or interface you use it with like:

```
type ABC = { a: string, b: boolean, c: number }
```

It's easy to make new types using the utility:

```
type TypeofA = Unpack<ABC, 'a'>
// ☝️ TypeofA = string
```

But can we compose a utility with a type already injected?

```
type Unpacker<T> = unknown // <- what goes here? ‍♂️
type UnpackABC = Unpacker<ABC> // <- to use like this
```

Then it would be reusable without referencing the ABC type...

```
type A = UnpackABC<'a'> // string
type B = UnpackABC<'b'> // boolean
type C = UnpackABC<'c'> // number
```

Comment: Could you show your use case?  I think I see where you're going with this, but I would suggest against it because it complicates things and makes it harder for somebody to understand what the code is doing, which defeats the typing system to an extent.

Comment: There are no [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) in TypeScript, so there's no good way to represent this transformation.  You can push things down from the type level to the value level and use functions to fake it up, but it leaves a lot of useless code all over the place and it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting re higher kinded types, but went a bit over my head. Probably right about not being worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example in the question, you can write it like this, without defining a separate `Unpacker` type:

```js
type UnpackABC<K> = Unpack<ABC, K>
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to "fill in the blank" in your example to make it work, though. If it were possible it would have to be like this, semantically if not syntactically:

```js
type Unpacker<T><K> = Unpack<T, K>
```

That is, what you want would be like [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which is possible for functions but not for types.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the confirmation I was looking for, that currying is not possible with types. Shame, would be pretty useful.